# Use of dispatchers in systems

Tags: java, design-patterns, solid-principles

**What is the relevance of the dispatcher in the system below?**

Is this a pattern/principle?

[image: Requesting the elevator]

I am not able to surmise the relevance of the `Dispatcher` here.

As per literature,there is one `Dispatcher` for each car, whose main function is to
calculate the target moving direction and destination for the car, as well as to maintain the opening time for the doors. The `Dispatcher` interacts with nearly all the control objects in the system except for `LanternControl`.

Why wouldn't the `HalButtonController` talk directly to the `Drivecontrol`?
What is the responsibility that a `DriveControl` cannot perform - and needs a `Dispatcher`?

Answer (score 0):

The button and drivecontrol are stateless - the dispatcher is responsible for maintaining the state in the system.  Without the dispatcher, then if two buttons were pushed then they'd both send their inputs to the drive control and the system would crap out (or else the drive control would simply ignore one of the inputs); instead, the dispatcher intercepts the button inputs and queues them appropriately (i.e. changes the system state to reflect the button inputs), then sequentially dispatches them to the drive control.